# Swift : How to merge two Realm Results in on in swift

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm, mongodb-realm

I am querying realm for two different keywords then I want to merge those two realm result into one so I loop through its.

I have this `Object` descendent class:

```
class Item: Object {
  @objc dynamic var _id: ObjectId? = nil
  @objc dynamic var _partitionKey: String = ""
  @objc dynamic var productBrand: String? = nil
  

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "_id"
    }
 }
```

I'm fetching the realms

```
class SearchResult : ObservableObject {
      @Published var storeitems: Results<Item>
     
    storeitems = realm.objects(Item.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "_id") 

     let p1 = self.storeitems.filter("productDescription CONTAINS '"Cheese"'")
    let p2 = self.storeitems.filter("productDescription CONTAINS '"Blue"'")
}
```

I am trying to merge p1 and p2 to get something like

```
 p3 = p1 + p2
```

How can this be implemented with realm result?

Comment: did you Find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust your filter to get what you want in one go:

```
let items = storeitems.filter { item in 
    item.productDescription.contains("Cheese") || item.productDescription.contains("Blue")
}
```